# Rails Runner or Rake task to send one-off email to registered users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, actionmailer

I'd like to send a one off email to users and, being new-ish to **ActionMailer**, not sure how to approach a one-off like this? **Rails Runner**, a **Rake task** or maybe even the **rails console** on the production machine?!?

Figure I'd add an action for it to `user_mailer.rb`. And create an accompanying view in `app/views/user_mailer/`. Just not sure how to trigger it. I'd like to grab a few users and send to them in batches. Happy to do this manually...as we stagger sending the messages over the next few days/weeks.

Appreciate any suggestions or advice.

Comment: The delayed_job gem might be something to have a look at: https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job I think it might do what you are looking for. With the possibility to manually run tasks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this as automatedly as possible, I'd take a look at the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever). It lets you automate rake (or runner) tasks as cron jobs. You can add a script somewhere in `lib` that uses ActionMailer to generate the emails, and schedule when they're sent with whenever/cron.

As far as sending in batches,
I would do something like this:

```
Users.find_each(:batch_size => n) do |m|
  mail = UserMailer.new(m.email_address, message)
  mail.deliver
end
```

Obviously, that's near-pseudocode, but hopefully it puts you on the right track?

Comment: Obviously, that assumes the user has an `email_address` attribute, and the second argument to your mailer is `message`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking to "automate as much as possible". I'm looking for a 'one off' solution. I just haven't created my own Rake or Runner scripts, yet, so looking for an **example** comparing & contrasting the two and/or advice on one over the other.

Comment: If it's one off, you could put the above code (basically) in lib/ and just execute `rails runner lib/mailscript.rb`. Using a rake task is usually more suitable for things that need to happen repeatedly.